# when last character deleting from input box, event is not firing in kendo grid and angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular5

I applied multi filter to kendo grid , my application developed in angular 5, here problem that, when deleting last character from input box that time event is not firing. how can fix this issue.

example if i type some thing in input box 'alen' , dataStateChange function will each time, same thing in removing 'alen' last three later removing that time function will but first character remove or delete it will not call(dataStateChangefunction).please help me any one.

### html

```
<kendo-grid
          [data]="gridData"
          [sortable]="{ mode: 'multiple' }"
          [sort]="sort"
          [filterable]="true"
          (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
          [height]="500" 
        >
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="120">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" width="230">
        </kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
</kendo-grid>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    private filter: string;
    private sort: SortDescriptor[] = [];
    private gridView: GridDataResult;
    private products: any[] = [
      {
        "ProductID": 1,
        "ProductName": "Chai",
        "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
        "Discontinued": false
    },
       {
        "ProductID": 3,
        "ProductName": "Chai",
        "UnitPrice": 122.0000,
        "Discontinued": true
    }
                               ,{
        "ProductID": 2,
        "ProductName": "Chang",
        "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
        "Discontinued": false
    }];

    constructor() {
        this.loadProducts();
    }

    protected sortChange(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
        this.sort = sort;
        this.loadProducts();
    }
    public state:State={
            logic: "and",
            filters: [
                { field: "ProductID", operator: "contains", value:''},
                { field: "ProductName", operator: "contains", value:''},
                { field: "UnitPrice", operator: "contains", value:''}

            ]
        }
    public dataStateChange(State:DataStateChangeEvent):void{
    this.state=State;
    data: process(products, this.state),
}
    private loadProducts(prods): void {
      const products = prods || this.products;
        this.gridData = {
            data: process(products, this.state),
            total: products.length
        };
    }
```

Comment: Please help me any one

Comment: Hello can you please help me

Comment: did that answer help you?

Answer (score 8):

Add `[filter]="state.filter"` to the **kendo-grid selector**.
I was facing the same issue and it got resolved when I did the above.

Answer (score 0):

I added [filter]="state.filter" it is working for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31740171)